# Bolzmann Distribution question

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy

I am busy working through an Astronomy textbook. I am presently working in the formation of spectral lines section.
I'm struggling with the statistical weights of the Boltzmann Distribution statistical equation:
$$\frac{n_i}{n_j}=\frac{g_i}{g_j}e^{-\frac{E_i-E_j}{k_BT}}$$
$n_i$ and $n_j$ are the population levels of exited atoms. $i$ is a higher level than $j$.
$g_i$ and $g_j$ are the statistical weights of the sub-levels.
$E_i$ and $E_j$ are the energies of the relative levels in electron volts.
$k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant $8.6\times10^{-5}\,e$V/K.
T is the temperature in Kelvin.

Assuming there is a nebula of Hydrogen gas. If it is required to discover the ratio of population of atoms in level two $(i=2)$ versus the ground state ($j=1$), $g_2=8$ and $g_1=2$. There are 8 quantum sub-levels on the second level and 2 sub-levels on the first level. So this gives a weighting ratio of four times for the quantum model to that of the simple Bohr model.

My problem is that there is only one electron, and it can only be in one sub-level at a time. If it's in the one of the two sub-levels of level one, it has a binding energy of $-13.6\,e$V. If it's in any of the 8 sub-levels of level two, it has a binding energy of $-3.4\,e$V. This due to "degeneracy".

My main question is: Why would it be four times more likely for an electron to be in level two versus the simple Bohr model when the energies are the same as the Bohr model levels.

A similar question leading on from this is: If the nebula is not in a magnetic field then the quantum state of $m_\ell$ (magnetic quantum number) is always zero and hence not available. This means that the weights should evaluate to 2. Again, there is only one electron and it can only choose one sub-level. All the sub-levels have the same binding energy due to degeneracy. So why is it more likely for the electron to be in the second level when there is a magnetic field and there are more sub-levels available?

Comment: There is no restriction that the $m_{\ell}$ value has to zero if there is no magnetic field.  No magnetic field just means that the $m_{\ell}$ levels all have the same energy (ignoring relativistic corrections).

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For ease of use, I will be using the modern and standardised notation and terminology, that astronomy is also supposed to be using. Maybe the book you are using is just that old, but you should switch to what everybody else uses. I will define what an orbital is, later inside the text. Each orbital can hold two electrons due to spin-half, and that means that there are two specific *states,* where here a specific state denotes everything that there is to know about that particular electron, and can only hold one single electron. This terminology conflicts with "ground state" and "excited states", which explicitly allows for degeneracy, i.e. "there are two ground states" and "there are many excited states of this specific energy level". Sadly, both conflicting definitions are in concurrent widespread use, and one has to infer from context.

Later, when you learn about *term symbols,* you will learn another definition for term and levels. Levels would be the atomic or molecular equivalent of orbitals, but the entire atom or molecule can only be in a single state; my definition of the singular specific state is chosen to agree with this definition and be as little confusing as possible.

The principle quantum number, that determines the energy of the electron in the isolated Hydrogen atom, is $n$, and would correspond to a level in a term symbol.

> If the nebula is not in a magnetic field then the quantum state of $m_\ell$ (magnetic quantum number) is always zero and hence not available. This means that the weights should evaluate to 2.

This is a misconception on your part. A bizarre one. The energy difference that a tiny magnetic field $B=B_z$ causes on an atomic level is
$$\tag1\Delta E\propto m_\ell\cdot B$$
and this equals zero when the magnetic field goes to zero. When there is no magnetic field, the $m_\ell$ quantum numbers are still valid and not necessarily zero.

> Why would it be four times more likely for an electron to be in level two versus the simple Bohr model when the energies are the same as the Bohr model levels.

You should simply not be thinking in terms of Bohr model, for it is just too wrong for this purpose.

When $\ell=0$, then $m_\ell$ can only be $0$

When $\ell=1$, then $m_\ell=-1,0,+1$

When $\ell=2$, then $m_\ell=-2,-1,0,+1,+2$

In general, there are $2\ell+1$ states of $m_\ell$ for every $\ell$ value.

When $n=1$, then $\ell$ can only be $0$ (and so can $m_\ell=0$ only).

When $n=2$, then $\ell=0,1$

When $n=3$, then $\ell=0,1,2$

In general, $\ell$ runs from $0$ to $n-1$, i.e. exactly $n$ cases to consider.

Each $(n,\ell,m_\ell)$ denotes a specific orbital, and each orbital can hold 2 electrons due to spin-half.

There is only one orbital for $n=1$, and for $n=2$ there are 4 orbitals. Each *single orbital* there is a $e^{-(E_i-E_j)/k_BT}$ probability of occupation. Since there are 4 orbitals with the same energy, each has the same probability of occupation, naturally that means that there are 4 times as much such probability as when there is only one single orbital at that energy. This is at the level of permutation and combinations before you can start dealing with probability and statistics, assuming constant probabilities.

Comment: Thank you. The last paragraph has helped a lot.